# Prepared statement select inside values() is this right way to do it?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is this right way to right prepared statement when you have to run select stement inside value which is usually values(?)

```
   function permission_table($conn, $username) {
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO perm (user_id) VALUES(SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
            $stmt->execute();
}
}
```

Comment: Perfectly valid.  You don't need the `if` condition though.

Comment: The question sounds like you are receiving an error. Could you please add that? Likely just `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I would just directly use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here, without the `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO perm (user_id)
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?;
```

Your updated PHP code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO perm (user_id) SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare(sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```